# Fetch records based on two column. One record if both column have same value else 2 records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have use-case wherein, we have a table lets say **table_a**

table_a have multiple columns, Lets consider 3 **a, b & c**.

**table_a**

```
|a|b|c|
|1|1|x|
|2|3|y|
```

**Output required**

1. If a and b have same value then required one records.
2. If a and b have different value then required two records.

Expected output:

```
|a|b|c|
|1|1|x|
|2|3|y|
|2|3|y|
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: What if there are already two datasets for (1,1,x)? Should one be removed or are they independent?

Comment: @LutzHorn, I have searched a lot. But I didn't get any clue from where to start. Thats the reason, I put my question over here.

Comment: @S-Man, For sure, we'll have multiple datasets. Here x is representing value of various other columns. For simplicity, I just put one column. Also, all the records are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2adf1eb5bc25921c90abaa6045325752)

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    table_a t,
    unnest(CASE WHEN a = b THEN ARRAY[1] ELSE ARRAY[1,1] END)
```

A set-returning function may duplicate the records. In this case the `unnest()` function expands the array which is created as parameter. If `a` equals `b` then an array is created with only one element. In this case the `unnest()` function expands only one record. Otherwise a two-element-array is created which results in an expansion with two records.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without arrays using a lateral join:

```
select t.a, t.b, t.c
from t cross join lateral
     (values (1), (2)) n(n)
where n.n = 1 or t.a <> t.b;
```